# How do i read the url and use it as a condition in knex form?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

```
router.get("/stocks/symbols/:industry", function (req, res, next) {
  req.db
    .from("stocks")
    .select("name","symbol","industry")
    .where('timestamp', '=', '2020-03-24T00:00:00Z')
    .where("industry", "like", '%h%')
    .then((rows) => {
      res.json({ Error: false, Message: "Success", Cities: rows })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      res.json({ Error: true, Message: "Error in MySQL query" })
    })
})
```

Above is the code for getting stocks with industry that includes h in it.
Such as Healt'h' Care and Information Tec'h'nology

What I'm trying to do is instead of using `'%h%'` to get the fixed response, use `req.params.industry`

What do i have to do to fix it?

Comment: Not sure who was here, but It worked after erasing one ``

Comment: What i've tried earlier was to use ' ' not ` `